# Working in IDLE, Tkinter window doesn't open without mainloop() but errors with it

Tags: tkinter, python-idle

I am very new to making GUIs.  I am working in IDLE (2.7.3) and want to open a simple window with a button.  Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
win=Tk()
button1=Button(win, text = "ok", command = sys.exit, foreground = "red")
button1.pack()
mainloop()
```

If I don't use `mainloop()` the window won't open.  If I DO use `mainloop()` I get this error when I click on the 'ok' button and the window with the button won't close:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\GUI.py", line 6, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 325, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1412, in __call__
    raise SystemExit, msg
```

Comment: I just tried the posted code in 2.7.8 and 3.4.2 and the difference is that the traceback is suppressed, but the tk window still remains.  Junuxx is correct that (Tk-instance).destroy is the proper callback.

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code to a python file and ran it from the command prompt on Windows 7, it worked fine. Maybe it's a problem with your Tkinter installation?

By the way, the "mainloop" line is mandatory. In a rough way of explaining it, that's what keeps the UI drawn to your screen.

Comment: Yep, runs fine for me too.

Comment: Ah of course, it does give the error in IDLE. IDLE is a Tkinter application itself which can give trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Tkinter stuff in IDLE, try replacing `command = sys.exit` with `command = win.destroy`. This way your widget gets destroyed, but you don't mess up IDLE itself, which also depends on Tkinter running.

These discussions are also relevant:

- [Exiting tkinter when using IDLE](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/29278-exiting-tkinter-when-using-idle)
- [Exiting a tkinter gui program](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/66698/exit-a-tkinter-gui-program)